# How to get sum and average of values from a pandas dataframe using values in multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I've the following dataframe -

```
df1
```

| Location | Office | ROP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Barcelona | Head Office | 4.3% |
| Bengaluru | Corporate Office | 9.6% |
| Chicago | Head Office | 12.5% |
| Luxembourg | Corporate Office | 14.1% |
| Paris | Head Office | 12.7% |
| Toronto | Head Office | 11.5% |
| Berlin | Corporate Office | 14.3% |
| Bengaluru | Head Office | 4.6% |
| Luxembourg | Head Office | 7.1% |
| Berlin | Head Office | 5.3% |
| Luxembourg | Virtual Center | 10.1% |
| Berlin | Virtual Center | 12.3% |
| Paris | Virtual Center | 9.7% |
| : | : | : |
| : | : | : |
| : | : | : |

```
a = ['Berlin','Paris','Luxembourg',...]
b = ['Head Office','Corporate Office',..]
```

Say there are multiple values in lists a and b, how do I find the sum and average of ROP based on the values in the lists and the given dataframe?

**Example:**

Say we have data from above mentioned dataframe in 'df2'.

df2 has just the visible 13 rows from dataframe 'df1'.

a = ['Berlin','Paris','Luxembourg']

b = ['Head Office','Corporate Office']

**Expected output:**

Sum: 14.3%+5.3%+12.7%+7.1%+14.1% = 53.5%

Average: (14.3%+5.3%+12.7%+7.1%+14.1%)/5 = 10.7%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
# convert ROP column to float:
df["ROP_int"] = df["ROP"].str.strip("%").astype(float)

a = ["Berlin", "Paris", "Luxembourg"]
b = ["Head Office", "Corporate Office"]

# create a mask
m = df["Location"].isin(a) & df["Office"].isin(b)

# compute sum and average from the mask and ROP_int column:
s = df.loc[m, "ROP_int"].sum()
avg = df.loc[m, "ROP_int"].mean()

print(s)
print(avg)
```

Prints:

```
53.49999999999999
10.7
```